# Create Table and Immediately Copy Data Over

Tags: php, mysql, copy, create-table

I have a table of users called 'cumulative' and those users can apply for a higher level of permission. This application sends an email to the administrator (me) and I review it. The data is also saved in a database called applications. In the email I supply myself with two links that accepts/rejects the user. In the case of accepting, I am having an issue with one small piece of it but I cannot understand why it won't work:

Below is a few lines of PHP/mysql code that show where the problem seems to appear:

```
$create = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $schoolname LIKE johns_hopkins_university");
$activated1 = mysql_query("UPDATE cumulative SET schoolname='$schoolname' WHERE id='$id'");
$activated2 = mysql_query("UPDATE applications SET role='Accept' WHERE id='$id'");
$captain = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO $schoolname
        SELECT *, 'Captain', 'Admin'
        FROM cumulative 
        WHERE email='$email'") or die("Copy Query didn't work");
```

First, the creating of the new table (`$schoolname`) works. Next, denoting this activation on both the cumulative user table, and the applicant table, works great, but what doesn't work is that when I try to copy over information from cumulative to the new table, it won't do it. I have included the die function but that isn't triggered and the copy supposedly is being processed but there is no resulting row in the new table.

Is there perhaps a different way to create and add data to a new table other than what I have above? Is there a different underlying issue?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have all in one table and add a field indicating to which school the data belongs?

Comment: if die() is not trigged, possible tha select from cumulative retrive 0 rows, check the result of "SELECT *, 'Captain', 'Admin' FROM umulative 
WHERE email='$email'"

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).